# How do I upload a file to Firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

```
<head>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-app.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-auth.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-database.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-storage.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" value="upload" id="fileButton"/>
<progress value="0" max="100" id="uploader">0%</progress>
</body>
</html>

////Inside index.js////

var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "***",
authDomain: "***",
databaseURL: "***",
projectId: "***",
storageBucket: "***m",
messagingSenderId: "***",
appId: "***", 
};

// Initialize Firebase //
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Upload File //
var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');

fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
var file = evt.target.files[0];
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('files_new/' + file.name);
var task = storageRef.put(file);

task.on('state_changed', 

function progress(snapshot) {
var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
uploader.value = percentage;
},
function error(err) {
console.error();
},
function complete() {
console.log('success!');
}
);
});
```

**What am I doing wrong? files are not uploading to the storage and progress bar is not working either.**

All addresses and keys from config are correct as other functions from index.js are working, **i.e Authentication**

I did the whole thing from this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpxHVrpfGgU

Comment: did you check the console? what error does it show?

Comment: Yes I checked. No errors in console.

Comment: have you checked the storage by visiting there? Try adding console log on each event. This will tell you where is it failing. Or if event are occurring.

Comment: The storage remains empty. I've added console.log('success!'); in function complete() {
  console.log('success!');
}  still not getting anything in console.

Comment: I am not sure if this can help, Can you add JQuery reference in the start of all JS files?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. I am not using Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's wrong is the reference. Get the storage ref first then create a child. Here is an example that works (at least for me):

```js
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
const fileRef = storageRef.child('files_new/' + file.name);
const task = fileRef.put(file);

task.on('state_changed',
  (snapshot) => { /* progress */ },
  (error) => { /* error */ },
  () => { /* complete */ }
)
```

with `file` beeing your file as above mentioned.

Comment: Thanks but I am struggling to understand your code. I did this from the official firebase video on this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpxHVrpfGgU

Comment: What is unclear to you, maybe I can tell you? The difference to your code is only in line 1 and 2 of my snippet. You need to create a child node to your storage ref.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. I am new to this. I am learning to do from documentation and videos

Comment: Simply replace the line `var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('files_new/' + file.name);` with `const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(); const fileRef = storageRef.child('files_new/' + file.name);` from my code.

Comment: Still not working. Here is how it looks now `var file = evt.target.files[0];
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  var fileRef = storageRef.child('files_new/' + file.name);
  var task = fileRef.put(file);

task.on('state_changed',
  (snapshot) => { /* progress */ },
  (error) => { /* error */ },
  () => { /* complete */ }
)`

Comment: Can you have a look at the browsers devtools (on chrome strg+alt+i or cmd+alt-i (mac), switch to the "Network" task and click all. Then run the request again and have a look at the changes. Especially red items with "4xx" http errors are helpful.

Comment: Nothing happens no new requests